# boost::any replacement for the code below

Tags: c++, templates, boost, casting, boost-any

I wish get rid of boost dependency on my code. I have the following struct construct. When calling and using this struct at another place in the code `boost::any_cast` is used. I know a template class would do it, but finding it hard to write this template. - C++ Rookie.

```
 struct Properties {
 public:
 Properties() {}
 Properties(const std::string &s, const boost::any & p) {
      name = s;
      value = p;
 }

 template <typename T>
 Properties(T n) {
      value = n;
 }
 boost::any value;

 std::string name;
};
```

Comment: The program uses a variable: std::vector<Properties*> prop; and another instance of BOOST usage is boost::any_cast<T>(prop[i]->value);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for fun, I thought I'd create a minimalist any implementation:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
// my_any.hpp
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

struct my_any
{
    my_any() = default;
    template <typename T> my_any(T const& v) : _storage(new storage<T>(v)) { }
    my_any(my_any const& other)              : _storage(other._storage? std::move(other._storage->clone()) : nullptr) {}

    void swap(my_any& other)               { _storage.swap(other._storage); }
    friend void swap(my_any& a, my_any& b) { a.swap(b); };
    my_any& operator=(my_any other)        { swap(other); return *this; }

    // todo move semantics
private:
    struct storage_base { 
        virtual std::unique_ptr<storage_base> clone() = 0;
        virtual ~storage_base() = default; 
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct storage : storage_base {
        T value;
        explicit storage(T const& v) : value(v) {}
        std::unique_ptr<storage_base> clone() { return std::unique_ptr<storage_base>(new storage<T>(value)); }
    };
    std::unique_ptr<storage_base> _storage;
    template<typename T> friend T      & any_cast(my_any      &);
    template<typename T> friend T const& any_cast(my_any const&);
};

template <typename T> T& any_cast(my_any& a) { 
    if (auto p = dynamic_cast<my_any::storage<T>*>(a._storage.get()))
        return p->value;
    else
        throw std::bad_cast();
}

template <typename T> T const& any_cast(my_any const& a) { 
    if (auto p = dynamic_cast<my_any::storage<T> const*>(a._storage.get()))
        return p->value;
    else
        throw std::bad_cast();
}
```

You can then use it precisely the same fashion as your use-cases showed:

```
struct Properties {
    public:
        Properties(const std::string &s="", const my_any& p={}) 
            : name(s), value(p) {}

        template <typename T> Properties(T n) { value = n; }

        std::string name;
        my_any value;
};

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<Properties> Props;

int main()
{
    Props v;
    v.emplace_back("bye", 42);
    v.emplace_back("vector", v);

    std::cout << "v.size(): "          << v.size()                           << "\n";
    std::cout << "v[0].value: "        << any_cast<int>(v[0].value)          << "\n";
    std::cout << "v[1].value.size(): " << any_cast<Props>(v[1].value).size() << "\n";

    v[0].value = v;

    try {
        std::cout << "v[0].value: " << any_cast<int>(v[0].value) << "\n";
    } catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << " exception caught, ok!\n";
    }

    std::cout << "v[0].value.size(): " << any_cast<Props>(v[0].value).size() << "\n";
}
```

See the output **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3c84eac8fb77493)**

Comment: error: 'virtual my_any::storage_base::~storage_base()' declared virtual cannot be defaulted in the class body                      Also, on the line: "Properties(const std::string &s="", const my_any& p={}) 
            : name(s), value(p) {}" I get error: expected primary-expression before '{' token

Comment: Oh well. You didn't name a compiler... :|

Comment: So here goes: **[MSVC12 ok](http://rextester.com/CVHWF11127)**, [GCC 4.8 ok](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3c84eac8fb77493), [Clang 3.5 ok](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69b25ed4f8b5a946). *AH*. You must be using [gcc 4.6](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8ce7f08ccc0ff9b). Well the fix is obvious :)

Comment: g++4.6.3 . removed "= default" added #include <typeinfo>  for bad_cast and used         Properties(const std::string &s, const myany &p) {
            name = s;
            value = p;
        }.....Everything works. Can't rep up..since I need 15 rep to vote up. Many thanks.

Comment: @user3204803 You can always accept the answer that helped you most in the end. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work (no need to accept mine, of course)

Comment: Is it possible to get this on older version of C++. My stuff still uses gcc 4.4.3. I've tried enabling C++11, but nullptr isn't supported. I followed www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf but still got " no match for ternary ‘operator?:’"

Comment: @user3204803 Does this help http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5585ef6c9a33ab35 ? I don't have a 4.4 compiler available. You _could_ of course do replace `unique_ptr` with `boost::scoped_ptr` or a raw pointer + rule of three/five... That's tedioius but not very complicated

Answer (score 1):

`boost::any` uses type erasure to store objects of any type, and you can assign it values of different types at runtime. The `any_cast` is used to retrieve the original value, with the correct type, that was stored in the `any` object. For instance, your current class allows you to do this

```
Properties p("int", 42);
std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(p.value) << '\n';
p = Properties("string", std::string("hello"));
std::cout << boost::any_cast<std::string>(p.value) << '\n';
```

You cannot just convert the class above into a template and get identical functionality. If you do that, you'll only be able to store a single type of value. And you must change the entire `struct` into a template, not just the constructor.

```
template<typename T>
struct Properties {
 public:
 Properties() {}
 Properties(std::string s, T p)
 : name(std::move(s))   // should use initialization list instead
 , value(std::move(p))  // of assignment within the body
 {}

 Properties(T n)
 : value(std::move(n))
 {}

 std::string name;
 T value;
};
```

However, the code I posted above is now illegal.

```
Properties<int> p("int", 42);
std::cout << p.value << '\n';
// p = Properties<std::string>("string", std::string("hello"));
// will not compile because Properties<int> and Properties<std::string> are
// distinct types
```

If these restrictions are OK, then the modified definition should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the restriction are not OKay. The program uses a variable: std::vector<Properties*> prop; and another instance of BOOST usage is boost::any_cast<T>(prop[i]->value);

Comment: @user3204803, then I'm afraid you'll have to stick to `boost::any` or roll your own.

Comment: @user3204803 I'm afraid Jefffrey is right; rolling your own is pretty much the only other option in that case. Thankfully, `boost::any` is relatively simple to implement, [here's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/any.hpp) the source code (it'll get a lot shorter than that if you get rid of the various compiler workarounds and other options)