# boost::bind cannot bind to non-static function template member type defined in pure virtual base class

Tags: c++, function, c++11, boost, callback

../1.63/boost/bind/bind.hpp:75:22: Type 'void (*)(const uint32_t &)' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members

My code looks something like:

```
template<typename T>
using RunStep = void (*)(const T& steps);

template<typename StepType, typename T>
class Stepper
{
public:
 virtual void StepUp() = 0;
protected:
  RunStep<StepType> runStepCallBack;
  T data;
}


class StepperIO : public Stepper<uint32_t, std::string>
{
 virtual void StepUp()
 {
    boost::bind(runStepCallBack,this, _1); //
 }
}
```

Is it even possible? Its just a psuedo-code

Comment: Are you trying to bind a variable? `runStepCallBack` is not a function!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist `runStepCallBack` is a member of type `RunStep<StepType>` which is a function pointer, so you can use `bind` on it.

Comment: @NulledPointer Explain what you want to in the end - How are you gonna use the result of `boost::bind`? It's completely unclear what you want to do here... `runStepCallBack` is a pointer to a function that takes a `uint32_t` and you're trying to bind it with `this` which is of type `StepperIO*` + something.

Comment: @Holt I want runStepCallBack to be part of pure virtual class to for that to be a generic interface for all the deriving class. StepperIO::Execute() will then call this function with instance of StepperIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the callback must also access the members of the actual stepper instance, then, no. Either

1. you explicitly pass the `this` argument into the callback (public API's often use an "opaque" argument like `void* user_data`)
2. or create a function object, e.g. using a lambda, boost::bind, std::bind or manually. Function objects can hold state. The standard library and boost have a type-erasing container for such callbacks: **`std::function<void(T)>`** (or `boost::function<...>`).

Demos:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cce4438aafa52527)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using RunStep = boost::function<void(const T& steps)>;

template<typename StepType, typename T>
class Stepper
{
    public:
        virtual void StepUp() = 0;
    protected:
        RunStep<StepType> runStepCallBack;
        T data;
};

class StepperIO : public Stepper<uint32_t, std::string>
{
  public:
    template <typename F>
    void setCallback(F f) { runStepCallBack = f; }
    virtual void StepUp() { runStepCallBack(1); }
};

struct Sample {
    void foo(int32_t i) const { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << i << ")\n"; }
    void bar(int32_t i) const { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << i << ")\n"; }
    void qux(int32_t i) const { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << i << ")\n"; }
};

int main() {
    StepperIO io;

    Sample demo;
    io.setCallback(std::bind(&Sample::foo, demo, std::placeholders::_1));
    io.StepUp();

    io.setCallback(boost::bind(&Sample::bar, demo, _1));
    io.StepUp();

    io.setCallback([&demo](int32_t i) { demo.qux(i); });
    io.StepUp();
}
```

Prints

```
foo(1)
bar(1)
qux(1)
```

My feeling is that the type-erasure is exactly what you were looking for, see more enlightening answers:

- Just type-erased storage: [boost::any replacement for the code below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176190/boostany-replacement-for-the-code-below/21197931#21197931)
- Type-erased polymorphic interface:

  - [Generating an interface without virtual functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859699/generating-an-interface-without-virtual-functions/18859931#18859931)
  - [Storing function pointers with different types c++ boost::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495784/storing-function-pointers-with-different-types-c-boostbind/26498462#26498462)
  - more samples [Container for boost::multi_array of same type but with different dimentionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670408/container-for-boostmulti-array-of-same-type-but-with-different-dimentionality/26674802#26674802)

Comment: Added reference to type-erased polymorphism, because it "smells like" you are looking for that

Comment: @NulledPointer Sure! It means that the type 'void (*)(const uint32_t &)' cannot be used prior to '::' . In other words, that type (that you pass, it's `RunStep<uint32_t>`) is being used before `::` (you can obviously just look at line 75 of boost/bind/bind.hpp, where you'll obviously find something like `::result_type` or similar in column 22. Just a guess.